# Python list & dictionary cross-reference

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Quick question, suppose I have a list and a dict:

```
menu = {'apple': 3.49, 'banana': 2.49, 'grape': 3.99, 'orange': 1.99}
order = ['apple', 'orange']
```

What I want is apparent, to calculate the total price (sum of the value) of what I ordered, using the value in the dict.
Obviously, I can not:

```
for item in order:
    if item in menu:
        print(sum(menu[item]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
menu = {'apple': 3.49, 'banana': 2.49, 'grape': 3.99, 'orange': 1.99}
order = ['apple', 'orange']
print(sum(menu[i] for i in order))
```

Output:

```
5.48
```

Comment: Wow this is great, saves even more lines than using a for in assumption in the head.

Comment: @jxie0755 Glad to help! If this answer is what you were looking for, please accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to do a list comprehension and a simple for-loop in one. Pick one or the other.

If you're doing a simple for-loop, you'll need a "sum_count" variable on the outside of the for-loop:

```
total_payment = 0
for item in order:
    if item in menu:
        total_payment += menu[item]
```

But you can use the `sum()` function in a list comprehension:

```
print(sum([menu.get(item, 0) for item in order]))
```

This shouldn't fail for items that aren't in the menu, because then the `.get()` function will just return 0 (which will not affect your total payment in the end).

Comment: Note, you could also exchange the list comprehension for a generator expression and save a whopping 2 characters! -->  `sum(menu.get(item, 0) for item in order)` ... And they're right pinky characters on english keyboards ...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
menu = {'apple': 3.49, 'banana': 2.49, 'grape': 3.99, 'orange': 1.99}
order = ['apple', 'orange']

myList = []

for item in order:
    if item in menu:
        myList.append(menu[item])

print(sum(myList))
```

The reason yours did not work is because when you're iterating over your dictionary, you're not storing the dictionary values, so you need to create an empty list to store the dictionary values, then sum the items in the list at the end.

Comment: Wow, Thanks!! Did not realize to create another empty list to contain the items. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[]
menu = {'apple': 3.49, 'banana': 2.49, 'grape': 3.99, 'orange': 1.99}
order = ['apple', 'orange']
for item in order:
   a.append(menu.get(item))
print(sum(a))
```

You could try this